# HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake - laravel api with flutter

Tags: php, android, laravel, api, flutter

i created a flutter application that Fitch dynamic data from laravel api which is hosted on shared hosting, the application works nice and fast but when there is multiple users testing it, it give me the error "HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake" whenever i try to get or post to the api, i tried taking off the limit of the api requests but still the same error occurs.